# MySQL - Return rows that don't have both values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the data:

tbl_apples

```
  Name    | Fruit   
+=========+========+

  James   | Apple   
  Marie   | Apple
```

tbl_bananas

```
  Name    | Fruit   
+=========+========+

  James   | Banana
  Timothy | Banana    
  Kevin   | Banana
```

I want to return all names that did not buy both apples or bananas. So in this case, it would be everyone except for James. Is there a simple way to do this for a massive data set (in the millions)? If possible, I want to be able to return those who only bought apples and not bananas, or bought bananas and not apples. 
EDIT: Looks like it might require a join, as I just found out that the banana data and the apple data are stored on two different tables. So how can I display them cohesively and then find out who bought only one or the other?

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic further down the road.

Comment: i left the PRIMARY KEY out just for the sake of brevity; i was looking more for a theoretical prod in the right direction

Comment: Tip: Never leave out the PK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by unifying the tables:

```
select  t.name
from (
    select  a.name, 'Apple' as fruit
    from    tbl_apples a
    union
    select  b.name, 'Banana' as fruit
    from    tbl_bananas b ) t
group by t.name
having count(distinct fruit) < 2
```